# How to parse JSON object to a string with js

Tags: string, json, parsing

I have JSON object and i would like send it as string to php file. How to convert JSON object to string with js/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.stringify({your object here})

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify(jsonObject)` will give you jsonObject converted into a string. Its available natively in most modern browsers. For backward compatibility you can include [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Answer (score 0):

```
**Check this out it will be helpful**

//index.php
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var json1 = {"test1":"TEST1","test2":"TEST2","test3":"TEST3","test4":"TEST4"};
 str = "data="+JSON.stringify(json1);

 $.get('test.php',decodeURI(str),function(html){ alert(html); },"html");
 });

</script>

//test.php

echo $GET['data'];
```