# unable to print json response in html

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am unable to print the json response in restective table....please help me out if I am doing something wrong....I just have to display the response in the html page

```
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("load");
     $.getJSON("http://10.0.2.2:8080/v1/service/1",
    function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(id, obj){ 
         $("#display tbody").append("<tr>");
            $.each(obj, function(propName, value) {

                 $("#display").append("<td>");
                 $("#display").append(value);
                 $("#display").append("</td>");
               // console.log(propName + ": " + value);


            });
             $("#display").append("</tr>");
        });  


    }); 

      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

       });

    function onDeviceReady(){
     navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");

       } 



   </script>

     </head> 
    <body>
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="3" id="display">
    <tr align="center">
        <td bgcolor="#474646" style="color: #fff;> Date</td>
        <td bgcolor="#474646" style="color: #fff;>Date</td>
        <td bgcolor="#474646" style="color: #fff;>Number</td>
        <td bgcolor="#474646" style="color: #fff; >Number</td>
        <td bgcolor="#474646" style="color: #fff; >Count</td>
        <td bgcolor="#474646" style="color: #fff; >Amount</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
        </html>
```

do I have someother option to display the response in table instead of using the above code
please let me know if something is wrong or something is to be changed

Comment: can you post your JSON data? is this URL "http://10.0.2.2:8080/v1/service/1" accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Parse your JSON data to String type to display as html.

Syntax: JSON.stringify({json object});

Visit [How to parse JSON object to a string with js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389305/how-to-parse-json-object-to-a-string-with-js)

Comment: jQuery already includes the $.parseJSON function, that uses json.js there is no need to include this stringify function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.getJSON("http://10.0.2.2:8080/v1/service/1",
     function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(id, obj){ 
     $("#display tbody").append("<tr>");
        $.each(obj, function(propName, value) {
            val = JSON.stringify(value);
             $("#display").append("<td>");
             $("#display").append(val);
             $("#display").append("</td>");
           // console.log(propName + ": " + value);


        });
         $("#display").append("</tr>");
    });
```

unable to print even after parsing the json data